# ibm connections assigning file to folder

Tags: ibm-connections

I have a problem when I try to assign a file with folder, the file and folder exist in the system but when I use the method for upload the folder of the file the response it's success but the file not figure into the folder.

I use the method

```
POST /basic/api/collection/{collection-id}/feed
```

in the collection-id I change for the folder UUID but don't works.

you know how assign a file to folder?

```
System.out.println("Uploading " + fileName + " in " + parentFolderName);
            Abdera abdera = new Abdera();
            Factory factory = abdera.getFactory();
            Entry entry = factory.newEntry();

        //Entry
            entry.setTitle(parentFolderName);
            entry.setId(parentFolderUUID);

            InputStream in = req.getInputStream();
            entry.setContent("application/pdf");
            entry.setLanguage("en");

            AbderaClient abderaClient = new AbderaClient(abdera);
            abderaClient.addCredentials(Utils.configJson.getString("connectionsServerURL"), null, null, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(connectionsUser, connectionsPassword));

        //Nonce
            String nonceUrl = "https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/files/basic/api/nonce";
            ClientResponse respNonce = abderaClient.get(nonceUrl);
            StringWriter writerNonce = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(respNonce.getInputStream(), writerNonce, "UTF-8");
            String nonce = writerNonce.toString();


        //Multipart-post options 
            RequestOptions options = abderaClient.getDefaultRequestOptions();
            options.setSlug(parentFolderUUID);
            options.setContentType("multipart/mixed");
            options.setAcceptLanguage("en");

            options.setHeader("X-Update-Nonce", nonce);
            fileURL = fileURL + "?X-Update-Nonce=" + nonce;


            ClientResponse resp = abderaClient.post(fileURL, entry);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the method signature, I think you are missing two items:

One
Content-Type header should be

```
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
```

Two payload of itemid (the id there is the id of the file I want in the folder/collection).

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<entry>
<itemId xmlns="urn:ibm.com/td">aca70bd1-0925-42c1-8196-b1c3042178a6</itemId>
</entry>
</feed>
```

Comment: ok but how I send the itemId? I tray send the itemId in the fileURL but don't work.

Comment: you should use a payload / xml body or generate an Abdera Feed object

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the answer of @Paul, the final code it's there.

```
Abdera abdera = new Abdera();
            Factory factory = abdera.getFactory();
            Entry entry = factory.newEntry();

        //Entry
            entry.setUpdated(new java.util.Date());
            entry.setTitle(parentFolderName);
            entry.setId(parentFolderUUID);

            InputStream in = req.getInputStream();
            entry.setContent("application/atom+xml");
            entry.setLanguage("en");

            AbderaClient abderaClient = new AbderaClient(abdera);
            abderaClient.addCredentials(Utils.configJson.getString("connectionsServerURL"), null, null, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(connectionsUser, connectionsPassword));
            System.out.println("added abdera client credentials");

        //Nonce
            String nonceUrl = "https://connectionsww.demos.ibm.com/files/basic/api/nonce";
            ClientResponse respNonce = abderaClient.get(nonceUrl);
            StringWriter writerNonce = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(respNonce.getInputStream(), writerNonce, "UTF-8");
            String nonce = writerNonce.toString();


        //Multipart-post options 
            RequestOptions options = abderaClient.getDefaultRequestOptions();
            options.setSlug(parentFolderUUID);

            options.setContentType("application/atom+xml");
            options.setAcceptLanguage("en");
            options.setHeader("itemId", docUUID);

            fileURL = fileURL + "?itemId="+docUUID;

            System.out.println("fileURL+++++: " + fileURL);



            ClientResponse resp = abderaClient.post(fileURL, entry, options);
```